# New user bullied into deleting question [only 10k users can see]

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, new-users, etiquette

I just found a blatant example of a [new user who was bullied into deleting a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512869/create-s-shap-corner-image-transparent-with-css-js). Since the question is no longer there, this is the only method I know of reporting the user's behavior. **How do I report a user when the content is only available on a deleted question / answer?**

Comment: **Meta is not used to target users**. Now, what is the question you're asking?

Comment: I agree, that conversation was... unfortunate, to say the least. Not sure whether there's anything we can do though, as the question seems very broad and would probably have been closed. You can flag for moderator attention, if it's a continuous pattern there may be consequences for the user.

Comment: Are you sure you want to report the *user*? Anyway, IMO the question is not that good.

Comment: @Pekka웃 he can't flag a 404 page

Comment: @Braiam fair point. I can, though, I think (and you can always flag something else and paste the link)

Comment: @Tunaki the reason I haven't given any names is so that 10k users are the only ones who can see what happened. I do believe that I'm trying to use as much discretion as I can

Comment: A better question instead is: how are you able to see a deleted question?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts *this is the only method I know of reporting the user's behavior* does not sound like wanting discreting at all.

Comment: @Tunaki there's my question.

Comment: Well... you certainly got attention drawn to it... I've cleared up the conversation as it's not necessary (and to ruin everyone's fun of course :p)... Next time, if you can't flag the post you're asking about, either flag another of the user's posts, or even one of your posts with a link and explain what you think is going on.

Comment: @JonClements If you write that as an answer, I'll upvote and accept. I just wasn't aware of what the procedure was for this kind of situation.

Comment: @Jon yeah, probably not. I still think the user should receive some feedback about his tone from *someone*. I bet it's not the first time.

Comment: @Patrick it's one that crops up fairly often - I'm sure someone will remember the most appropriate duplicate sooner rather than later.

Comment: @Braiam I saw the question and the comments chain before it was deleted, and kept the tab open while I was writing this question.

Comment: This is answered by a moderator [on this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340456/is-there-a-way-to-flag-a-spammy-user-account-that-has-only-contributed-to-docume): `...and they have no posts to flag, feel free to flag a random post for moderator attention and direct our attention to the problematic profile using the flag message.`