# Is there a way to flag a spammy user account that has only contributed to Documentation?

Tags: support, feature-request, spam, accounts

I read both [Flag user profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285204/6381711) and [Why aren't user accounts that only post spam auto deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306663/6381711), even though relating to flagging a user's profile/account, they do not address my quest: how to Flag spammy user accounts *(so as to draw moderators' attention)*.

Being confronted to an unprecedented situation while performing reviews today on StackOverflow *Documentation: Proposed Changes*, I was looking for a way to possibly flag specific user accounts that were flooding documentations with spammy contents; all my daily reviews were all about rejecting these numerous spams.

In such a situation, where a given user account is solely used for flooding documentations with spam edit, updates and newly created contents; what can one do so as to draw moderators' attention and or possibly trigger an automatic (whether temporal or definite) restriction so as to save reviewers' time for more productive interventions?

Is there any current mechanisms in place for such a control, user account sanctioned after a given number of flagged posts by other users as well as a possible removal of subsequent available suggested edits and or posts submitted by that given user?

*If none of the above features are not available as it seems to be; I hope they will be considered!*

Imagine a situation were such accounts are not kept in check, it may get to a time were things will get out of hands: *[all] reviewers spending several days cleaning gross spammy contents that could have been prevented in the interest of worthier inputs*.

Comment: Related : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339215/how-to-report-users-spamming-in-documentation-requests

Comment: FYI, this flood of spammy Documentation is already [on the mod's radar](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340455/4751173), and moreover, since it involves multiple accounts, flagging just one of them is not going to solve the problem.

Comment: Multiple reviewers have hit their Documentation review cap fighting this. We need extra help from those in power!

Comment: Shog9 created a script  that is running now to nuke the users. Leaves us with the proposed changes, unless the event of nuking the user also removes the proposed changes. But there wasn't time to verify if that is true.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Don't worry about flagging these particular spammers, we're destroying them as quickly as we can find them. [This isn't their first appearance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339215/how-to-report-users-spamming-in-documentation-requests).

For regular, one-time spammers on the main site moderators tend to catch them as they are spamming and destroy their accounts in response to flags. For those we miss, we have queries to find spam-flagged posts and destroy remaining users.

If someone is a particular and persistent problem, and they have no posts to flag, feel free to flag a random post for moderator attention and direct our attention to the problematic profile using the flag message.

Comment: Flagging a random post for moderator attention will leave a trace in the history of that post. Could we have an alternative?

Comment: @Cœur: You don't have to make your random selection uniform across all posts by all users.  I suggest selecting randomly from the set of moderator-authored posts that instruct you to flag a random post.